# how does terraform understand which cluster to use while creating namespace using kubernetes_namespace

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I am trying to understand how terraform resource understand which cluster to use while creating the namespace if i have multiple clusters in my projects.

example main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.5.0"
    }
  }
}
variable "example1" {
  
}

provider "kubernetes" {
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "aks_namespace" {
metadata {
  name = "aks_namespace"
}
}
```

In this example how does terraform know which cluster to use for creating namespace?

Comment: It's using the system default most probably.

Comment: It is derived from the provider configuration. The authentication information you provide to the kubernetes provider will only target a single cluster. Since no information is provided here, it will be the default context in the default `kubeconfig` on the local filesystem (just like normal for the k8s API).

Comment: That is not great, when you create a nodepool with azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool you pass in kubernetes_cluster_id so it references the correct cluster, surely that would be a better solution here